# DRF: Get request object in custom renderer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, renderer

I'm building a serverside using django==1.10 and djangorestframework==3.4.6

I have build a JSONRenderer:

```
class CustomJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):
     def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        meta_fields = ["temp_save", "subject", "visit"]
        a = {"fields": {}}
        for k in data:
            try:
                meta_fields.index(k)  # Crashes with ValueError if not found
                a[k] = data[k]
            except ValueError:
                a["fields"][k] = data[k]
        return super(CustomJSONRenderer, self).render(a, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

**Question:** Is it possible to get the views `request` object? I specifically want to access the urls parameters (e.g `request.kwargs['pk']`

Comment: I have updated my answer...@Vingtoft

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get request from `renderer_context` as following.

```
request = renderer_context['request']
```

## Your Code:

```
class CustomJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):
     def render(self, data, accepted_media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        request = renderer_context['request'] or None
        meta_fields = ["temp_save", "subject", "visit"]
        a = {"fields": {}}
        for k in data:
            try:
                meta_fields.index(k)  # Crashes with ValueError if not found
                a[k] = data[k]
            except ValueError:
                a["fields"][k] = data[k]
        return super(CustomJSONRenderer, self).render(a, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)
```

May be this will help you.

Comment: I get the following error: AttributeError: 'DosageRenderer' object has no attribute 'renderer_context'

Comment: You were almost right: I needed to use the renderer_context passed as a param to the function "render". Please update your answer so I can accept it.